# Python: format datetime efficiently whilst leaving it as a datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, formatting

I want to be able to format a datetime object, while leaving it as an object. I have worked a way to do it, but it doesn't seem very efficient.

My specific aim is to limit the extra digits on the seconds to 2. This is how I am currently doing it:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
now_frmt = datetime.datetime.strptime(now, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Cheers,
JJ

Comment: Can you clarify? Formatting a datetime object shouldn't change the object itself; `strftime` returns a new string, while `strptime` makes a new datetime object. Do you mean you want it to store only 2 digits for the seconds (which it already does)? Are you referring to the microseconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this to subtract off the microseconds:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
now_frmt = now - datetime.timedelta(microseconds=now.microsecond)
```

To round to the nearest second you can do the following:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
delta = (0 if now.microsecond < 500000 else 1000000) - now.microsecond
now_frmt = now + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=delta)
```